# How to create Approval Sheet

Tags: tables, formatting, thesis

Our campus expected us to prepare approval sheet like shown in the figure [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnIIg.png]]. Here is the code

```
\newpage
\section*{Approval Sheet}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Approval Sheet}
\begin{huge}
Wollo University
Kombolcha Institute of Technology
Department of Information Technology
Post-Graduate Program in Computer Networks and Communications \\[1.5cm]
\end{huge}

As member of the examining board of the final M.Sc. open defense, we certify that we
have read and evaluated the thesis done by \textbf{Name of Researcher} entitled with \textbf{Title Name} and recommend that it be accepted as fulfilling the thesis requirement for the degree of Master of Science in Computer Networks and Communications.\\[1.5cm]

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{\linewidth}{@{}p{2.5cm}@{}X@{}@{}p{2.5cm}@{}@{}X@{}p{2.5cm}@{}}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}& &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{} && \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \tabularnewline
&  &  &  & \tabularnewline
\cline{1-1} \cline{3-3} \cline{5-5}
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{\small Name of Chairman} & &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Signature}} && \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textb{Date}}\tabularnewline[1ex]
&  &  &  & \tabularnewline
\cline{1-1} \cline{3-3} \cline{5-5}
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{\small Name of Internal Examiner} & &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Signature}} && \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textb{Date}} \tabularnewline[1ex]
&  &  &  & \tabularnewline
\cline{1-1} \cline{3-3} \cline{5-5}
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{\small Name of External Examiner} & &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Signature}} && \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textb{Date}} \tabularnewline[1ex]
&  &  &  & \tabularnewline
\cline{1-1} \cline{3-3} \cline{5-5}
\end{tabular}

Final approval and acceptance for the thesis is contingent upon the submission of the final copy the thesis to the Council of Graduate Studies (CGS) through Departmental Graduate Committee (DGC) of the Information Technology department.

\begin{tabular}{\linewidth}{@{}p{2.5cm}@{}X@{}@{}p{2.5cm}@{}@{}X@{}p{2.5cm}@{}}\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Name of the Advisor}}& &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Signature}} && \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Date}} \tabularnewline
\end{tabular}
```

The error I found is this:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Welcome! Can you provide code for a minimal working example and tell us what problem you're having implementing this? Note this is not a do-it-for-me site and questions without code tend to attract little by way of help. They are also frequently closed. Right now, we don't know what you find hard about this, so it's practically impossible to help.

Comment: Your best bet is to start by asking if your institution has a style file for your project. This might be official, but often it is unofficial. If you don't know other people using LaTeX, ask in the maths department.

Comment: I edited the post. The error is this https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ks1ki170mascP5vHzhoSyYJpZjqZZSW8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Error I got when I compile https://imgur.com/laFZZYA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a working example. However, I don't know your document class. It should be working anyway.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Approval Sheet}
\begin{center}
\Large\bfseries Wollo University\vspace{0.5cm}

Kombolcha Institute of Technology\vspace{0.5cm}

Department of Information Technology\vspace{0.5cm}

Post-Graduate Program in Computer Networks and Communications
\end{center}\vspace{1cm}

As member of the examining board of the final M.Sc. open defense, we certify that we
have read and evaluated the thesis done by \textbf{Researcher name} entitled with \textbf{Title of Research} and recommend that it be accepted as fulfilling the thesis requirement for the degree of Master of Science in Computer Networks and Communications.\vspace{1cm}

\noindent\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lll@{}}
First Last & &02/10/2023 \\[-1ex]
\rule{3cm}{1pt} & \rule{2cm}{1pt} & \rule{2.5cm}{1pt} \\
Name of Chairman & Signature & Date \\[2em]
\rule{3cm}{1pt} & \rule{2cm}{1pt} & \rule{2.5cm}{1pt}\\
Name of Internal Examiner & Signature & Date\\[2em]
\rule{3cm}{1pt} & \rule{2cm}{1pt} & \rule{2.5cm}{1pt}\\
Name of Internal Examiner & Signature & Date\\
\end{tabular*}\vspace{1cm}

Final approval and acceptance for the thesis is contingent upon the submission of the final copy the thesis to the Council of Graduate Studies (CGS) through Departmental Graduate Committee (DGC) of the Information Technology department.\vspace{1cm}

\noindent\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lll@{}}
\color{blue}First Last &  & \color{blue}Oct 2,2023 \\[-1ex]
\rule{3cm}{1pt} & \rule{2cm}{1pt} & \rule{2.5cm}{1pt} \\
Name of Thesis Advisor & Signature & Date \\
\end{tabular*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're answer is a light in a darkness 